# When i am using DJ browser in my swing code in ubuntu facing issue with libwebkitgtk

Tags: java, swing, djnativeswing

This is the sample code i'm using for Poc purpose......but i'm not able to go forward in linux environment(if i dont install libwebkitgtk package ) but this code is working fine in windows..but in linux libwebkitgtk is required.

```
public class SimpleWebBrowserExample {

  public static JComponent createContent() {
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    webBrowserPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Native Web Browser    component"));
    final JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
    webBrowser.navigate("/home/mphs/Softwares/eclipse/Home/Softwares/ews/Platform     /src/Sample.html");
     webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPane.add(webBrowserPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // Create an additional bar allowing to show/hide the menu bar of the web browser.
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 4, 4));
    JCheckBox menuBarCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Menu Bar",    webBrowser.isMenuBarVisible());
    menuBarCheckBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        webBrowser.setMenuBarVisible(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
      }
    });
buttonPanel.add(menuBarCheckBox);
contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
return contentPane;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    NativeInterface.open();
    UIUtils.setPreferredLookAndFeel();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DJ Native Swing Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(createContent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
    NativeInterface.runEventPump();
}

}
```

This is the StackTrace i'm getting...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.processCommandResult(MessagingInterface.java:342)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.syncSend(MessagingInterface.java:329)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.syncSend_(SWTNativeInterface.java:392)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.syncSend(NativeInterface.java:104)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.Message.syncSend(Message.java:64)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.CommandMessage.syncExec(CommandMessage.java:55)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.runSync(SWTNativeComponent.java:201)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.createNativePeer(SWTNativeComponent.java:1006)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.access$17(SWTNativeComponent.java:989)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent$12.run(SWTNativeComponent.java:882)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent$CMN_createControl.run(SWTNativeComponent.java:663)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.CommandMessage.runCommand(CommandMessage.java:61)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.runMessageCommand(NativeInterface.java:172)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.runMessageCommand(SWTNativeInterface.java:1429)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.runMessage(MessagingInterface.java:121)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.processReceivedMessages(MessagingInterface.java:106)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.access$2(MessagingInterface.java:94)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface$2$2.run(MessagingInterface.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface$OutProcess.runNativeSide(SWTNativeInterface.java:1352)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.main_(SWTNativeInterface.java:1461)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.main(NativeInterface.java:224)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.core.NativeWebBrowser.createControl(NativeWebBrowser.java:431)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: I know what is missing u need to install that libs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Weblibs in Ubuntu.

**command**

> sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0

It worked for me. Restart your application after installing this. Hope this will help you too.

Comment: but it will help your for only ubuntu i dont have any solution for mac still.

Comment: my actual requirement is i need to run with out installing libwebkitgtk in my system...bcoz this code is going to be executed in hundreds of production machines as it is a retail project

Comment: @veeraprathapm so this will help :) and ya let me know if u can find for mac.